# Shortcut In Atom editor to move to previous screen in Mac

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, atom-editor

While browsing codebase in Atom editor, we can go to the definition of a function by right click
& selecting the "Goto Definition" option.
However I do not see any shortcut to move back to previous screen (in MAC platform).

What's the shortcut key in Mac to move back to previous screen/file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following key combination is used to move back to previous screen in Mac.
<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> will launch the command palette and search the command you are looking shortcut for.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [cursor-history](https://atom.io/packages/cursor-history) package, which keeps a log of cursor jumps, and has keyboard shortcuts to navigate up/down previous positions

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @Yatin he asks for an inexistent feature on a plugin oriented program. The plugin is the answer, but I'm editing it to elaborate

Comment: *Any* answer (or pointer to something that might be useful or tangentially related) is better than no answer at all. Thanks @netizen